# How can i make my image carousal loop in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple image carousal but I would like it to go back to the start when the final slide item is reached so it appears to have a loop

My HTML:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider">

        <img class="slide" src="/assets/image-slide-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="slide" src="/assets/image-slide-2.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="slide" src="/assets/image-slide-3.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="slide" src="/assets/image-slide-4.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="slide" src="/assets/image-slide-5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button id="prev">
            <img src="/assets/icon-arrow-left.svg" alt="">
        </button>
        <button id="next">
            <img src="/assets/icon-arrow-right.svg" alt="">
        </button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
const slidesContainer = document.getElementById("slider");
const slide = document.querySelector(".slide");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");



nextButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const slideWidth = slide.clientWidth;
      slidesContainer.scrollLeft += slideWidth;

  });

  prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const slideWidth = slide.clientWidth;
    slidesContainer.scrollLeft -= slideWidth;
  });
```

Comment: It might sound wrong, but did you ever use conditionals?

Comment: I have used if statements before but I am not sure how to use it in this case

Answer (score 1):

For the `nextButton` event handler function you could add a conditional:

```
if (slidesContainer.scrollLeft >= slideWidth * 4) {
    slidesContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

and for the `prevButton` you would do the opposite:

```
if (slidesContainer.scrollLeft <= 0) {
    slidesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollWidth * 4;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have added this but it is only working for the previous button and not doing anything for the next button, please help?

Comment: Hi, please could you help with this again?

Answer (score 0):

If width (height, if slider is vertical) of slider is as long as, say, two images, place copies of last two images to the beginning of slider and whenever user reaches the end of slider move it to the very beginning